# When I add backround color, the button stops working

Tags: html, css

When I delete this line, it works perfectly but when I add, it doesn't.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>New</title>
<style>
button {
display: block;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px 15px;
color: #354259;
background-color: #ECE5C7;  <! -- this one -- !>
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button>Apply now</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What "works perfectly"? details, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. You are overwriting the default CSS for button element and not defining what to do when hovering, which is fine but it won't look good(CSS)

Try telling your element what to do onhover event like below.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>New</title>
  <style>
    button {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      color: #354259;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #ECE5C7;
      <! -- this one -- !>
    }
    
    button:hover {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      color: #354259;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: black;
      <! -- this one -- !>
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button>Apply now</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You are overwriting the default CSS for button,Use specipic css for your button. it will better ...
maybe you want this type button check this button it will help you...

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>New</title>
  <style>
    
    
    
button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #354259;
  background-color: #ECE5C7; 
  overflow: hiden;
  border:  1px solid;
}

    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button>Apply now</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue and Just added some styling.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #354259;
  background-color: #ECE5C7;  <! -- this one -- !>
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transform: translatey(-3px);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transform: translatey(0px);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Apply now</button>
```